# Valid dimension-metric combinations

Tags: google-analytics

According to the Google Analytics docs, [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#mode=api&cats=user,session,traffic_sources,adwords,goal_conversions,platform_or_device,geo_network,system,social_activities,page_tracking,content_grouping,internal_search,site_speed,app_tracking,event_tracking,ecommerce,social_interactions,user_timings,exceptions,content_experiments,custom_variables_or_columns,time,doubleclick_campaign_manager,audience,adsense,channel_grouping,related_products) is supposed to show the valid dimension-metric combinations.

Could someone explain how I can use this page to (for example) get a list of all the dimensions can be used with the `ga:users` metric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click on ga:users check box any dimensions and metrics that are not valid combined with it will become grayed out

[image]

There is no way to check for invalid dimensions programmatically besides sending the request to google via the Reporting API and getting an error back.

Comment: I guess I'm clicking on the wrong thing. You can see here a screenshot of what I see after clicking on the `ga:users` checkbox - nothing is greyed out http://imgur.com/j5eSRtB

Comment: you have it scroll down there aren't that many that are not valid.  Look under adwords section.

Comment: But this page doesn't tell the full truth. According to it you can combine ga:sessions and ga:pagePath. I would expect the number of sessions containing a special pagePath. But you get the number of sessions starting on this pagePath. This isn't documented well.